# Multi-column vlookup conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting, vba

I'm looking to create a conditional format for a worksheet based on a couple of things.

Sheet 1:

Reference: "Date" = Col1 Row1

```
    Date    Census          RN's On Schedule                
            7a  3p  11p     7a  3p  11p     
    1-Oct   8   8   9       8   8   9       
    2-Oct   10  14  13      13  16  13      
    3-Oct   10  12  12      12  12  10      
    4-Oct   12  10  10      11  11  10      
    5-Oct   10  11  11      11  12  11      
    6-Oct   10  11  14      11  12  12      
    7-Oct   13  12  12      12  14  12
```

Sheet 2:

Reference: "Census" = Col1 Row1

```
Census  RN Staffing Needs       
        7a  3p  11p     
1       2   2   2       
2       2   2   2       
3       2   2   2       
4       3   3   2       
5       4   4   3       
6       4.5 5   5       
7       5   6   6       
8       6   7   6.5     
9       7   8   7       
10      8.5 9   8.5     
11      10  11  10      
12      12  12  11.5    
13      12  12  12      
14      12  12  12      
15      13  13  13      
16      13  13  13      
17      14  14  14      
18      14  14  14
```

So here's the question.

I've got these values in sheet 1 that I'm looking to compare to sheet 2 and use conditional formatting to highlight certain things.  I need excel to look at the census (for reference, 1-Oct census is 8 @ 7a) from sheet one and find it in sheet two.  Then I need it to compare the number in **RN's On Schedule** to the number in **RN Staffing Needs** (RN Staffing Needs, in this case 6 @ 7a; RN's On Schedule, 8).  When the RN's on Schedule value from Sheet 1 (F3 in the case of 1-Oct) is HIGHER than the RN Staffing Needs from Sheet 2 I need a conditional format to highlight that value green.  When it is LOWER I need it to highlight that value yellow.  When there is an exact match nothing needs to happen.

I've tried vlookups and index/matches with nested IF statements and IFERROR's and the like... this one's a little out of my scope of practice.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the approach below, but you can probably consolidate it even more.

**EDIT**: I was able to consolidate it even more.

Apply this formula for conditional formatting for the Range(E3:E9) in Sheet1. Then make an additional rule, but change the formula to `>` and to fill green. Then you can use the same two formats against columns F and G and you just need to change the column references in your formula and the vlookup column indicator.

So, for column F, the formula would be `=F3<vlookup(C3,Sheet2!$A:$D,3,0)`

[image]

**LEAVING OLD METHOD IN HERE FOR MORE DETAILED UNDERSTANDING**

### Sheet1

Enter the formula seen in the formula in cell I3 and drag through the end of the range (K9)
[image]

### Conditional Formatting

Select the range from E3:G9 and apply the displayed formulas in the Conditional Formula Rules Manager.
[image]

For reference my sheet2 looks like this (based on your data displayed).

[image]

Comment: =IF(E9>VLOOKUP(B9,'SICE Guide'!$A:$D,L$1,0),"GREEN",IF(E9<VLOOKUP(B9,'SICE Guide'!$A:$D,L$1,0),"YELLOW",""))

My L$1 is your I$1, there's an additional data set.  So what is the I$1 referenced for?  I just want to be able to explain the function and how it's working... btw it's working, I'm going to input more data and see what I get. :)

Comment: Both methods worked!  You're a life saver Scott!  Now I just have to apply this to 38 other sheets and back fill three months worth of data!... See you in December when I come up for air! :P

Comment: Great! Glad it worked. Good luck with the dredging ...  The L$1 is referenced to get the vlookup column count. You can see I wrote 2 in that column (and 3, 4 in the columns next to it!)

Comment: Thanks again!  Couldn't have done it without ya Scott!