# Modify VBA To Account For Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to use a COUNTIF-like function in Excel 2016 to total up a series of cells by their background color... 3 different colors (green, yellow, red) representing 3 different 'states' (first largest, second largest, third largest). I managed to get it working by using this VBA coding:

```
Function Countcolour(rng As Range, colour As Range) As Long
 Dim c As Range
 Application.Volatile
 For Each c In rng
     If c.Interior.ColorIndex = colour.Interior.ColorIndex Then
         Countcolour = Countcolour + 1
     End If
 Next
 End Function
```

However, this particular code doesn't take into account conditional formatting.

So for example, I try to conditionally format a set of data to highlight its first largest value green, second largest yellow, third largest red. I use this VBA function in another block to get a count of all the green highlights. However, it doesn't pick up on the background color of the cell because of the conditional formatting.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... I feel like the first part of the `If` condition should be some form of `c.FormatCondition.Interior`, but I've tried variations on the theme with no success.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152458/counting-colored-cells-from-a-conditional-formatting-statement

Comment: if the conditional formatting color change according to the formula provided to the conditional formatting, use that formula in your VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This is something many people try to do including me.

There are some useful codes on the internet like http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CFColors.htm
but after searching a lot I found only ONE with the answer 
[get conditional formatted color with vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419269/get-conditional-formatted-color-with-vba-in-excel) and it works!

The solution is easy:

you can use

```
.cells(1,1).displayformat.interior.color
```

or

```
.cells(1,1).displayformat.interior.colorIndex
```

Example:

```
Function CountColor(ByRef rng As Range, ByRef color As Long) As Variant
    Dim total: total = 0
    If (Not (rng Is Nothing)) Then
        Dim element As Variant
        For Each element In rng
            total = total - (element.DisplayFormat.Interior.color = color) ' MINUS because TRUE evaluates to -1
        Next element
    End If
    CountColor = total
End Function

Sub test_countColors()
    With Sheet1
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim color As Long
        Dim total As Long
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3500, 55))   ' Or anay other range
        color = 8438015                                   ' Or any other color
        total = CountColor(rng, color)  
        MsgBox "Total= " & total
    End With
End Sub
```