# get conditional formatted color with vba in excel

Tags: excel, bubble-chart, vba

**Working:**
An excel bubble chart, with circles in different sizes and colors.

**Not Working:**
I get the colors by reading the color value with vba, however `Interior.Color` does not recognise the color set by conditional formatting.

Code in question:

```
Range("Z" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(srs.Name, Sheets("Diagrammdaten").Range("a:a"), 0)).Interior.Color
```

I can't find anything on a different selector than `Interior.Color`, but there surely has to be something like `Displayed.Color` in excel?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

to get the cell color.  Other CF properties are also accessible via `DisplayFormat`