# font color of data validation type cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data validation drop downs in my excel. if some one copy - paste invalid data into these dropdowns, if the pasted value is not matched with dropdown data I am highlighting text in red using conditional formatting .
Now I am trying to get the text color of this dropdown in case of mis matched data using VBA. but I am getting -4105 as the color index.

```
Function GetColorText(pRange As Range) As String

Dim xOut As Variant
Dim xValue As String
Dim i As Long
xValue = pRange.Text
MsgBox "cell value = " & xValue

xOut = pRange.DisplayFormat.fornt.Color
MsgBox "Color  = " & xOut

GetColorText = xOut
End Function
```

Can some one help to get the text color in case of mis mached data

Comment: To check the color set by conditional formatting, use  `pRange-DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47419269/7599798

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get conditional formatted color with vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419269/get-conditional-formatted-color-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: thanks for quick response. but this also not working for me. the function I had written in module and calling this function as excel formula in the sheet.

Comment: Don't understand how this is related to a function. Btw: If you want 
 to check the text color, use `pRange.DisplayFormat.Font.Color`

Comment: Please, don't post in comments. Edit your question and put it there.

Comment: in excel cell I am calling as =GetColorText(E41)

Comment: FunThomas - I have edited my code posted. please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DisplayFormat` in a UDF is not supported, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat.

There is a workaround using `Evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757688/7599798. In your case, simple replace `c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` with `c.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex`.

```
Function GetColorText(pRange As Range) As String
    if isempty(pRange) exit function 
    Dim xOut As Variant
    xOut = pRange.Parent.Evaluate("DFColor(" & pRange.Address() & ")")
    GetColorText = xOut
    Debug.Print pRange.Address; xOut
End Function

Function DFColor(pRange As Range)
    DFColor = pRange.DisplayFormat.Font.ColorIndex
End Function
```

**Update** If you don't want to return anything if the cell is empty, just add a check at the top of the routine. See the updated the code.

Comment: Thanks !!, I have used same code. It is working fine in case of  text is applied with conditional format. but if the cell is empty , it is returning same font color (in my case red.)  .Actually it should not return anything for empty cells. how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Below code is not triggering some times, after reading some article's I have added "Application.volatile"  statement in the UDF. still the UDF is not calling in th excel cell utill I got and hit Enter Key. kindly help on this.